# The result of subscribeWith is not used. - rx java android

Tags: android, rx-java2

This is my code snippet.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    disposableSingleObserver.dispose();
}

/**
 * fetches json by making http calls
 */
private void fetchContacts() {


    disposableSingleObserver = new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Contact> movies) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            contactList.clear();
            contactList.addAll(movies);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Received all notes
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // Network error
        }
    };

    // Fetching all movies
    apiService.getContacts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(disposableSingleObserver);
}
```

I am getting a warning The result of subscribeWith is not used.

What is the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

when you use `subscribeWith()`, it returns `Disposable` it self through which you can dispose the subscription at any time if you want. That eliminates your need to create a disposable for storing it in variable to dispose later. You can do something like this:

```
// Declare global disposable variable
private CompositeDisposable mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

// Then add the disposable returned by subscribeWith to the disposable
mDisposable.add(apiService.getContacts()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeWith(disposableSingleObserver));
```

And at any point of time, if you want to cancel the API call, then you can simply call like in onDestroy()
`mDisposable.clear();`

OR

more similar to the way you did it currently like: (Notice that the result of `subscribeWith()` is directly assigned to your `disposableSingleObserver` variable

```
disposableSingleObserver = apiService.getContacts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Contact>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<Contact> movies) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    contactList.clear();
                    contactList.addAll(movies);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // Received all notes
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                   // Network error
                }
         });
```

And dispose it in `onDestroy` like you are doing currently:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    disposableSingleObserver.dispose();
}
```